# JUnit test for testing RabbitMQ consumer and producer

Tags: java, junit, rabbitmq

I want to create JUnit test to test RabbitMQ producer and consumer. I tried this:

```
public class QueueConsumer extends TestCase {

    private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "logs";

    public static void Producer(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, BuiltinExchangeType.FANOUT);

        String message = "some test message";

        channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, "", null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");

        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }


    public static void Consumer(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, BuiltinExchangeType.FANOUT);
        String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
        channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "");

        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

        Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                    throws IOException {
                String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
            }
        };
        channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
    }

}
```

How I can run Consumer and Producer in separate threads in order to exchange messages between them?

For example Consumer threads sends 10 messages to Producer? I only get this result. No messages are delivered.

```
[x] Sent 'some test message'
 [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C
```